# Building U-Boot is failing

Tags: build, cross-platform, u-boot

I am trying to build u-boot

Toolchain:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130823131954/http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/toolchains/

U-boot: git.denx.de

I am following this site to build this u-boot

http://beagleboard.org/linux

It says to put cross compiler path before building.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin:$PATH
```

1) I can see angstrom folder in /usr/local. Also I think that we need the toolchain's actual place of binaries. Let suppose in /home/myhome/BBB/angtrom_x_y_z/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin

So which path actually i should export?

2)I have tried to put both paths, but I am getting errors.

3)I have downloaded three toolchains

```
 angstrom-2011.03-i686-linux-armv5te-linux-gnueabi-toolchain
 angstrom-2011.03-x86_64-linux-armv7a-linux-gnueabi-toolchain-qte-4.6.3
 angstrom-2011.03-i686-linux-armv7a-linux-gnueabi-toolchain-qte-4.6.3
```

1st gives errors as

```
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi- make am335x_evm
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config.h
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc: 0: No such file or directory
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc: unrecognized option '-G'
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mabicalls"
make[1]: *** [include/autoconf.mk] Error 1
make: *** No rule to make target `am335x_evm'.  Stop.
```

second one is I think for 64 bit processor, I have i386 one, so it also doesn't worked

Third one is corrupted.

Can anybody tell me how to compile it as the site says. Maybe the site is outdated but still if anybody can tell me a straightforward way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Angstorm toolchian is too old to deal with recent U-Boot. I tried your procedure and get other errors. I'm not sure why you try to use that old toolchain and if you have to use it. But I quickly check Linaro toolchain [gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.07_linux](https://releases.linaro.org/14.07/components/toolchain/binaries/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.07_linux.tar.xz), which I use for boards like Cubietruck and A20-OLinuXino-MICRO and it works fine.

```
git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git
cd u-boot
export PATH=${PATH}:${PATH_TO_TOOLCHAIN}/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.07_linux/bin
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make am335x_evm_defconfig
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make -j$(nproc)
```